# package org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver does not exist

Tags: java, jersey, glassfish, classpath, grizzly

Which JAR's need to be added **manually** (meaning *not* with Maven) to the classpath for `Jersey` and `Grizzly` to work as a REST client?  I've tried a few variation but cannot find specific JAR's.

specifically, output from ant:

```
-do-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/Jersey01/build/classes
    [javac] /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/Jersey01/src/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/helloworld/App.java:9: error: package org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver does not exist
```

I've tried adding grizzly core:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22grizzly-core%22

see also:

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/griz_jersey_intro/Grizzly-Jersey-Intro.html

http://www.andygibson.net/blog/article/simple-restful-web-services-with-glassfish/

Comment: Do you _know_ how to use Maven? If so, why don't you just create a new project with maven, adding the dependencies you need, then you will see all jars that it pulls in. That's how I would go about finding out. It's the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

with maven it is alot easier to manage dependencies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-grizzly2-http -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Else you can download it also from its repository